# Citation: Pour qui sont ces serpents

Tags: littérature, citations

> Pour qui sont ces serpents qui sifflent sur vos seins?

De qui est cette allitération?

Comment: Ce n'est pas une citation, ce n'est qu'un pastiche du célèbre vers de Racine (*Andromaque*, acte V, scène 5) « Pour qui sont ces serpents qui sifflent sur vos têtes ? ».

Comment: Sur vos têtes. Mais de qui est le "seins"?

Comment: C'est un pastiche... je ne pense pas qu'il y ait d'auteur identifié, je doute qu'on sache qui l'a dit en premier.

Answer (score 4):

Sur le web, on ne trouve cette phrase que dans *Dictionnaire universel de la langue française, avec le latin et les étymologies*, vol. 2, 6ème édition, 1823, par Pierre Claude Victoire Boiste, comme exemple de sigmatisme (multiplicité des lettres sifflantes), sans référence à une œuvre particulière. La phrase précise est :

> Pour qui sont ces serpents qui sifflent sur son sein ?

On peut peut-être lui attribuer...